# Build a lucene kind of query for searching text on various properties in neo4j Cypher 2.x

Tags: spring, search, neo4j, lucene, spring-data-neo4j

My Entity is in this way

```
public class event
    {
        String title;

        String description;

        String city;
    }
```

Now i want implement search feature when an user enters "Hello Hyderabad Fest"

I want token size the string and split into words and find Any word matches on any property on node

How can we achieve this using cypher query or building lucene kind of query,by the way i am using spring data neo4j3.x .
can we pass lucene query through neo4j named queries as query parameter.
Can we dynamicaly pass where condition in neo4j named queries
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The Cypher text search functions `STARTS WITH` and `CONTAINS` might be of help here:

```
MATCH (e:Event) WHERE e.title STARTS WITH {user_input}
RETURN e
```

or

```
MATCH (e:Event) WHERE e.description CONTAINS {user_input}
RETURN e
```

To tokenize on spaces and return any word matches across all properties you could try something like this:

```
WITH split({user_input}, " ") AS words
UNWIND words AS word
MATCH (e:Event) WHERE e.title CONTAINS word 
    OR e.description CONTAINS word
    OR e.city CONTAINS word
RETURN e
```

Where `{user_input}` in your example is "Hello Hyderabad Fest"